# Error placement using tooltipster and jQuery form validation plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I use jQuery form validation plugin [This one](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my form and [tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) to show errors messages.

The code working with no problems to validate the form and show errors the only problem appear when I show some hidden form elements after the error messages shows up.

So if I submit the form after showing the hidden elements (which is showed dynamically related to user choices ) there is no problem in error message placement,
but if the form submitted and the user choose to show the hidden elements after the error message appear the error position goes wrong.

HTML

```
<form id="eway" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="roww">
<select name="txtAmount" id="txtAmount" class="inputfield select" >
                  <option value="Amount">Select Amount</option>
                  <option value="5">$5</option>
                  <option value="10">$10</option>
                  <option value="15">$15</option>
                  <option value="25">$25</option>
                  <option value="50">$50</option>
                  <option value="70">$75</option>
                  <option value="100">$100</option>
                  <option value="Custom">Custom Amount</option>
                  </select>
</div>

<div id="customAmount" style="display: none;">
<div class="roww">
<input name="txtCustomAmount" type="text" id="txtCustomAmount" class="inputfield" placeholder="Please enter amount more than $1"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="roww">
<input name="txtLastName" type="text" id="txtLastName" class="inputfield" placeholder="Please enter your last name"/> </div>
<div class="roww"><input name="txtMobileNumber" type="text" id="txtMobileNumber" class="inputfield" placeholder="Please enter your mobile number"/></div>
<input type="submit" name="btnProcess" value="Process Transaction" id="btnProcess" class="go backcolr"/>
<form>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.cont
{
/*width:400px; height:470px; float:left; */
}
.roww
{
width:445px; height:auto; float:left; margin:5px 0;
}
.firts
{
width:180px; height:30px; float:left; font-weight:bold;
}
.second
{
width:210px; height:30px; float:left;
}
. firts span
{
 width:5px; height:25px; float:left; font-weight:bold; color:#F00
}
.showerror {border:1px solid #CE2726; padding:10px 15px; background:#FDE8E7; margin:5px 0 15px 0px; width:auto; color:#CE2726; ont-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;}
.showsuccess {border:1px solid #ACDBAD; padding:10px 15px; background:#ECFAE3; margin:5px 0 15px 0px; width:auto; color:#4F8A10; ont-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;}
.go {
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    float:right;
}
.inputfield {
    border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #E5E4E4 inset;
    color: #666666;
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 240px;
}
.select { padding:6px 10px; width: 270px;}
.clear { clear:both;}

</style>
```

AND JS

```
$("#txtAmount").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == 'Custom'){
            $("#customAmount").fadeIn();
        }else{
            $("#customAmount").fadeOut();
        }
    });
$('#txtAmount').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right'
    });
$('#eway input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right'
    });
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
        return arg != value;
       }, "Value must not equal arg.");

(function($,W,D)
{
    
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#eway").validate({
                 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
                    $(element).tooltipster('show');
                },
                rules: {
                    txtLastName: "required",
                    txtMobileNumber: "required",
                    txtAmount: { 
                        valueNotEquals: "Amount" 
                    }
                   
                },
                messages: {
                    txtLastName: "Please enter your lastname",
                    txtMobileNumber: "Please enter a valid mobile number",
                    txtAmount: "please choose donation amount"
                  
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: form.action,
                            type: form.method,
                            data: $(form).serialize(),
                            async: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            beforeSend : function (){
                                $('#loading').show();
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                var status = response.status;
                                var message = response.message;
                                $('#loading').hide();
                                if(status == 1){
                                    $('#error').hide();
                                    $('#result').show();
                                    $('#result').html(message);
                                    resetForm($('#eway'));
                                }else{
                                    $('#result').hide();
                                    $('#error').show();
                                    $('#error').html(message);
                                }
                                
                            }            
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
     $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
    $('#eway').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

also this the [jsfiddle.net Link](http://jsfiddle.net/fouad90/B7XYz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke tooltipster to reposition when the #textAmount changes. below you can have a look at the last three line I added. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B7XYz/11/

```
$("#txtAmount").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == 'Custom'){
        $("#customAmount").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("#customAmount").fadeOut();
    }
    $(".roww").children().each(function(){
        $(this).tooltipster("reposition");
    });
});
```